# How do I import my contacts from broken Galaxy S7 to new S7?

Tags: contacts, data-recovery, broken-screen

My Galaxy S7 got water under the cracked screen and now the screen is completely blank but the phone still works. My contacts are not backed up on Google or SD or SIM card.

All PC programs that can retrieve my contacts require me to turn on USB debugging, which I can't do because I can't see what's on the screen.

How do I move my contacts over to my replacement S7?

Comment: Please start with checking out [broken-screen tag-wiki](/tags/broken-screen/info) and the questions using that tag. You're certainly not the first one with this issue. If it's only the contacts: had you synced them somewhere (by default they are synced with Google)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! No USB debugging or root required! Use the Connect program on Windows 10 and watch this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=42yvWG-w49s. The video shows the option as "Screen Sharing" but that's only for LG phones. On Samsung the option is in the notification drop down and is called "Smart View." Works the exact same way.